# Meteor.. accounts- password-- Create account on client without login

Tags: meteor, account, meteor-accounts

I'm using [accounts-password package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-password) - Meteor.

I code interface for admin.

Admin will create accounts for other user.

```
Accounts.createUser({
        email: "abc@gmail.com", 
        password : "abc123", 
        profile: { name: register_name }
   });
```

But after this code executed, my application automatic login with account *abc@gmail.com*, wich i don't want it

**Question**

How to create accounts without automatic login?

I read `accounts-password` source but i dont know how to remove automatic login

I also tried to use Meteor.users.insert function but `Accounts.setPassword` didn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a normal behavior using accounts package, to avoid messing with the source code use a [Meteor.method](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods)/[Meteor.call](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call).

This is a simple example,also you can use the default `username` filed and not a `profile:{name:register_name}`.

```
    if(Meteor.isServer){
        Meteor.methods({
          createUserFromAdmin:function(emai,password,username){
            Accounts.createUser({email:email,password:password,username:username})
      }
    })
   }else if(Meteor.isClient){
        Template.admin.events({
         'click #createAccount':function(){
           Meteor.call('createUserFromAdmin',email,password,username,function(err,result){
              if(!err){
                 console.log("a new user just got created")
                }else{
                  console.log("something goes wrong with the following error message " +err.reason )
                }
             })
           }
        })
       }
```

With this you can create multiple accounts on the admin template, and keep the autologin behavior on the sign-up template (if you have one)

Comment: I am interested in using this approach but is there an issue with sending the password over the wire in plain text? Because that is what you are doing when you call the server side Meteor method to create the account.

Comment: @nearpoint it won't send the password over the wire because the Meteor method 'createUserFromAdmin' is wrapped inside isClient, so it all happened on the client side only.