# How to Disable "Auto-resume Login" / "Remember Me" functionality for Meteor Accounts

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

Meteor Accounts auto-resumes your login session by default, which is pretty handy for most applications.

However, in my case, I need to disable this functionality. What is the best/proper way to remove this feature so that if the browser window is closed and reopened, the login session does not persist?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should create the account on the server side, not on the client side. using a `Meteor.method/Meteor.call` check this SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29453829/meteor-accounts-password-create-account-on-client-without-login/29453912#29453912

Comment: I believe I read that discussion previously. If I read it correctly it seems the OP had problems with Meteor automatically logging into a new account when created in the admin panel. My question is regarding the auto-resume/"remember-me" functionality that happens when you open the app after being previously signed in.

Comment: Well you know, this could be a little jacky workaround, when you create the account you create with `Accounts.createUser({email:email,password:password,username:username},function(err,result){if(!err){Meteor.logout()}})` what we are doing here? if there is not error when the users gets created automatic perfumes an `Meteor.logout()' so the user will be get disconnected, if the `Meteor.logout()` don't work try using a `Meteor.setTimeout` that should work, you got the idea

Comment: I'm not creating users, users are already created. If I log into the account user@example.com and then close the browser or hard quit the mobile/cordova app, I want the user session to end. When opening the browser and accessing the app, the previously logged in user should not auto-login.

Comment: Ok so you should do a `Template.layout.onDestroyed(function(){Meteor.logout()})` if you are using the layout template.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I had a feeling that onDestroyed wouldn't run if someone exits the browser.

Comment: give it a quick try, if not we find another solution

Comment: That does not work for me unfortunately.

Comment: That is because the code didn't have a chance to run, the browser instance was already terminated.

Comment: @KevinIamburg did you fid any solution for this?